# Remove outliers withing training set in cross-validation

Tags: python, pandas, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to do a cross-validation but I want to remove outliers (eg. only lower than 0.95y) in the training sets, while keeping the test set intact. I am using:

```
cv_scores = cross_validate(reg, X=X, y=y_tr, cv=GroupKFold(n_splits=3), groups=groups, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=True, verbose=0)
```

for the cross-validation (function from sklearn.model_selection), however I dont know how to make the necessary changes.

Sample:

```
date id x1  x2   y
1    a  10  15  100
2    a  20  30  150
3    a  12  10  130
2    b  15  13  1000
3    b  16  19  90
1    c  18  12  700
2    c  20  15  60
```

For example: one of the training folders will contain ids a and b. In this case I want to remove the outlier (date 2 id b), while keeping the outlier in the test folder (date 1 id c). Similarly, in the a and c training folder, I should remove the (date 1 id c), while keeping the (date 2 id b).

Comment: Please provide additional information like - a sample dataset and for which column you want to filter outlier.

Answer (score 0):

Removing outliers is not recommended by most statisticians. Instead, you should analyze the outliers like using cook distance. Importantly, removing outliers from train data will cause data shift.